# Constructing confidence intervals for mean of means, using standard errors

Tags: confidence-interval, mean, standard-error, moving-average

Is it possible to construct confidence intervals for a mean of weighted means using standard errors?

I have 4 different weighted means ($p_t = \sum_{i=1}^{n} w_ip_i $ where $w_i$ is the respective weight) for $t = 1,2,3,4$ time periods, with $n = 16$:
\begin{equation}
\bar p_1 = 378.0494 \quad \bar p_2 = 349.1045 \quad \bar p_3 = 339.0127 \quad \bar p_4 = 338.8679
\end{equation}
with corresponding standard errors:
\begin{equation}
s_1 = 43.668 \quad s_2 = 42.133 \quad s_3 = 40.465 \quad s_4 = 40.084 
\end{equation}
Calculating a moving average ($\hat P_m$) of these:
\begin{equation}
\hat P_m = 351.2586
\end{equation}
Corresponding standard error:
\begin{equation}
s_{\hat p} = 9.246
\end{equation}